# Abstract DataContext in DLL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

I have a database schema and I'm attempting to create a "base" library around it. I have several other applications that use the same base tables and I would like to commonize the code.

So I guess I have two questions then.  Firstly, I'm using C#/Asp.net 4.0 and Linq2Sql because my database design has been around for a while and I haven't had time to convert it to the Entity framework.

I have created a .dbml file with the base functionality which provides a Linq Data Context that we'll call BaseContext that has all the common tables. I then have additional code that in the partial classes; this is the code I'm trying to make common. I then compile BaseContext into a DLL.

I then have an application(s) which will extend the schema and create a new DataContext that derives from BaseContext. This is my plan on paper, but 1) how does inheriting DataContexts work?

Secondly, I'm having issues with connection strings across applications. I don't ever need the code in the DLL to run, but I somehow need to be able to set the connection string of the derived application so that the common code is useful. 2) Is there a way to like override a connection string in a dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does inheriting DataContexts work?

Just like inheriting anything else. It's no different.

> Is there a way to like override a connection string in a dll?

Class libraries typically don't contain their connection strings; the host process does. The host process is usually a client application, or, even better, a service (WCF, etc...). It's customary for the connection strings to go in the host config file.

Note: The reason class libraries (DLLs) don't contain connection strings is because they don't know under which context (program) they're running. Within the class library code, it can still access ConfigurationManager to get a connection string. The host process just needs to make sure that connection string is defined it its app.config.

Comment: So the DLL can still access ConfigurationManager content that is defined by the application using the DLL? That's exactly what I want!  Does this require making an app.config file for the DLL and then a web.config for the application using the DLL?

Comment: Yes, the DLL accesses the config file of the hosting app. DLLs don't have app.configs; just the host processes.